# rails setup osx - 2.0.2 apps needing to upgrade to 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, osx-snow-leopard, rack-pow

Once a year or so, I need to update a few rails apps. This means that while I know the ruby language... I forget and don't keep up with the best practices of setting up the rails environment on osx 10.6.7. In the past year I got a new mbp... so I need to reconfig everything. One of the apps is 2.0.2 and two other apps are 2.3.x... so I'd like to also upgrade these as I make changes to them. I've heard good things about homebrew and pow so I installed those. And all would be well if I was writing a new app from scratch... but how do I run a rails v.2.0.2 app with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to run a rails 2.0.2 app with pow, unfortunately. Pow is a tool for running rack apps, and rails wasn't build on top of rack until version 2.3.